# Firestore document data returns undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have manually created a collection on firestore DB and added a document all manually. But when I query for the data of that document which exists in the DB, I get undefined for the document data. I have added the relevant code and console log.

`Code`

```
export const addLikes = async (postId, userId) => {
  console.log(`postId : ${postId}`);
  console.log(`userId : ${userId}`);
  await firestore()
    .collection('likesComments')
    .doc(postId)
    .get()
    .then(documentSnapshot => {
      console.log(
        `documentSnapshot : ${JSON.stringify(
          documentSnapshot,
          getCircularReplacer(),
        )}`,
      );
      console.log(
        `documentSnapshot.data() : ${JSON.stringify(
          documentSnapshot.data(),
          getCircularReplacer(),
        )}`,
      );
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
};
```

`console log print`

```
 LOG  postId : eJh3e7LcU4tGLfnw3Rbr
 LOG  userId : pdPu80SlluMVQgGiz6QvY1HAm022
 LOG  documentSnapshot : {"_metadata":{"_metadata":[false,false]},"_ref":{"_firestore":{"_app":{"_name":"[DEFAULT]","_deleted":false,"_options":{"storageBucket":"react-native-social-media-app.appspot.com","databaseURL":null,"apiKey":"AIzaSyAgkR8wcB4yTFcTp5_G210uiu_v0Ammv-A","gaTrackingId":null,"projectId":"react-native-social-media-app","messagingSenderId":"137374136152","appId":"1:137374136152:android:6f935d6007f819bc4dd72d"},"_automaticDataCollectionEnabled":true,"_initialized":true,"_nativeInitialized":true},"_nativeModule":{"RNFBFirestoreModule":true,"RNFBFirestoreCollectionModule":true,"RNFBFirestoreDocumentModule":true,"RNFBFirestoreTransactionModule":true},"_config":{"statics":{"CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED":-1},"version":"11.4.1","namespace":"firestore","nativeModuleName":["RNFBFirestoreModule","RNFBFirestoreCollectionModule","RNFBFirestoreDocumentModule","RNFBFirestoreTransactionModule"],"nativeEvents":["firestore_collection_sync_event","firestore_document_sync_event","firestore_transaction_event"],"hasMultiAppSupport":true,"hasCustomUrlOrRegionSupport":false},"_referencePath":{"_parts":[]},"_transactionHandler":{"_pending":{}}},"_documentPath":{"_parts":["likesComments","eJh3e7LcU4tGLfnw3Rbr"]}},"_exists":false}
 LOG  documentSnapshot.data() : undefined
```

Comment: could you please update the question with your database structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call .data() in your then block like this:

```js
.then(documentSnapshot => {
      console.log(
        `documentSnapshot : ${JSON.stringify(
          documentSnapshot.data(),
          getCircularReplacer(),
        )}`,
      );
```

Comment: documentSnapshot.data() returns undefined, you can see in my console log.